# Как разделить лист на два по предикату?

Tags: c#, list, linq

Имеется лист, из которого необходимо получить два согласно предикату. На данный момент делаю так:

```
var trueItems = new List<string>();
var falseItems = new List<string>();
var list = new List<string> {
    "one", "two", "three"
};
list.ForEach(x => {
    if(x.EndsWith("e")) {
        trueItems.Add(x);
    }
    else {
        falseItems.Add(x);
    }
});
```

Я думаю, что скорее всего имеется лучший способ, чтоб разделить лист на два согласно условию/предикату. Можно ли реализовать это стандартными средствами LINQ? Можно ли реализовать обобщенное расширение (по типу Where или Select в LINQ), которое бы принимало предикат и возвращало кортеж?

```
// хотелось бы так...
list.Split(x => x == null).Select((trueItems, falseItems) => { /* ... */});
```

Comment: Способ лучше, чем пройтись 1 раз по данным и заполнить нужные вам списки?

Comment: `Where или Select` принимает и отдает одно и то же, а вы хотите принять одно перечисление, а вернуть два - это разные вещи

Comment: @tym32167 думал, что для этого есть соответствующий метод. Where и Select были упомянуты в качестве примера, может быть не лучшего.

Comment: *Можно ли реализовать обобщенное расширение (по типу Where или Select в LINQ), которое бы принимало предикат и возвращало кортеж?* — можно, конечно, только зачем? проще написать один цикл и в нем копировать в 2 списка, либо просто написать 2 строчки с Where().ToList()

Comment: [подобное на EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4549339/312041)

Comment: Да, есть способ лучше: использовать цикл `foreach` или даже `for` - это устранит вызов лишнего метода (лямбды) на каждой итерации, т. е. будет работать быстрее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Благодаря @tym32167, @АндрейNOP и @Monk, авторам всех комментариев и [вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549339) на enSO пришёл к пониманию следующего:

- нет ничего страшного в использовании цикла, а при необходимости иметь в результате именно списки, то это вообще единственно возможный вариант с одним проходом;
- для решения задачи можно использовать [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-2.2) и [Lookup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=netcore-2.2);

```cs
var list = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
ILookup<bool, string> res = list.ToLookup(x => x.EndsWith("e"));
// IEnumerable<string> res[true]
// или так, но с дополнительным проходом
// List<string> nonMatches = res[false].ToList(); 

// Метод расширения должен быть определен в неуниверсальном статическом классе
public static (IEnumerable<T> matches, IEnumerable<T> nonMatches) SplitByPredicate<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, bool> keySelector) {
        var grp = source.ToLookup(keySelector);
        return (grp[true], grp[false]);
    }

var (matches, nonMatches) = list.SpliByPredicate(x => x.EndsWith("e"));
```

#### Ссылки по теме

- [ILookup<TKey,TElement> Interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.ilookup-2?view=netcore-2.2)
- [Lookup<TKey,TElement> Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=netcore-2.2)
- [Именованные и неименованные кортежи](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tuples#named-and-unnamed-tuples)

Answer (score 1):

```
list.GroupBy(x => x == null)
```

а дальше у вас две группы, ключ которых - true или false, обрабатывайте каждую группу как хотите.

Как этим потом пользоваться:

```
list.GroupBy(x => x == null).SelectMany(g => g.Key ? g.Select(x => ...) : g.Select(x => x...))
```

После операции группировки работаем мы уже с группами, у которых есть ключи. В данном случае это будет две группы данных, у одной ключ true, у другой false. Можно их после какой то обработки сложить обратно в одну коллекцию через SelectMany.

Comment: Не подскажете как получить доступ к true и false: list.GroupBy(x => x == null).Select(? => ?);

Comment: @XelaNimed добавил, но писал по памяти, примерно так.

Comment: Тогда уж не GroupBy, а ToLookup. Потом просто имеем доступ по ключу: `lookup[true]` или `lookup[false]` :)